# Django : Digital Ocean Spaces/AWS S3, how to create image using django_storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-imaging-library

I am trying to user django_storages package for storing images on AWS S3 or Digital Ocean spaces.

When I use normal image upload using a form, the image is successfully getting uploaded to the server.

But When I try to create an image manually and then write it to S3 or Digital Ocean Space buckets, the image is not getting created properly.

Following is the code which I have run on Shell and tried alot:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

img = Image.new('RGB', (500,500), (255,255,255))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((10,10), "Hello", font=ImageFont.truetype("tahomabd"), fill='BLACK')
d.text((10,60), "World", font=ImageFont.truetype("tahomabd"), fill='BLACK')


from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
JPEG_PATH = "pathtofile.jpeg"
storage.exists(JPEG_PATH)

storage.delete(JPEG_PATH)
JPEG_STORAGE = storage.open(JPEG_PATH, "w")
JPEG_STORAGE.write(img)
JPEG_STORAGE.close()
```

The above code creates a .JPEG file on the storage location but it is some default file which does not make any sense. 
Please suggest what is issue with the code.

Comment: 'some default file'.  what do you mean by this?

Comment: I meant, what ever is the size and content of the image, it’s creates a default file of same dimensions every time with same size of 58kb or so. For example I am trying to create an image of 500 x 500 px, but I creates same default file. If I try 1000x1000 again same. So may be it is not understanding how to save an image file, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is `django-storages` expects a file-like object, ideally with the file pointer at byte 0.

As you can see in the Pillow docs for the [`new()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) method, it returns a `Image` object, but it is not a file object.  More reference can be seen from following the code on Github for the `Image` module:

[`Image.new()`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L2266)

[`Image` module](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L504)

As an alternative, I would use a temporary file with your Pillow image creation.  Use that as a file object for your image, and pass that to `django-storages` for upload.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

temp_file = TemporaryFile()
img = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))
d = ImageDraw(img)
d.text(10, 10), 'Hello', font = ImageFont.truetype('tahomabd', fill = 'Black')
d.text(10, 10), 'World', font = ImageFont.truetype('tahomabd', fill = 'Black')
im.save(temp_file, 'JPEG')

temp.seek(0)
# upload to S3 using temp_file rather than image.  
# Don't forget to close all open file pointers too.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by temporary file? You mean to save file locally then transfer to S3 and then delete the local copy?

Comment: from tempfile import TemporaryFile
        temp_file = TemporaryFile()
        img.save(temp_file, 'JPEG')
        temp_file.seek(0)
        JPEG_STORAGE = storage.open(JPEG_PATH, "w")
        JPEG_STORAGE.write(temp_file)
        temp_file.close()
        JPEG_STORAGE.close()
I tried the way you suggested, but results are same. Same image gets created, which can't be opened. Like a currupt image file.